# Retrieving button value Issue Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button

Well I'm trying to change my button value after a click, because when its value is "Modificar(Modify)" I want to change to "Guardar(Save)" and vice-versa, but for some reason It's not working changing the value of the button, I've tried attr("value","...."), val("...."), and prop, but It's not working, and using html("..") or text("...") it erase the icon I have on it.

```
<?php 
require ('../conexion.php');

//Conectar con la base de datos y servidor
$conexion = new Conexion();
$conexion->conectar();

$idCentro = $_POST["idCentro"];

if ($idCentro != "" ){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM centro WHERE id_centro='".$idCentro."'";
    $consult = pg_query($query);    
}

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM parroquia";
$consult2 = pg_query($query2);


if($consult){
    $row = pg_fetch_array($consult);
    ?>
    <form name="registrarCentro" id="registrarCentro" class="registroCentro" method="post" action="">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label> Nombre del Centro</label>
            <input class="form-control" size="70" id="nombre" name="nombre" value=<?php echo "'".$row["nombre"]."'"; ?> readonly="readonly">
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label> Dirección</label>
            <input class="form-control" size="70" required:"required" id="direccion" name="direccion" value=<?php echo "'".$row["direccion"]."'"; ?> readonly="readonly">
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label> Tel&eacute;fono Principal</label>
            <input class="form-control" size="20" required:"required" id="telefono1" name="telefono1" value=<?php echo "'".$row["telefono_1"]."'"; ?> readonly="readonly">
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label> Tel&eacute;fono  Opcional</label>
            <input class="form-control" size="20" required:"required" id="telefono2" name="telefono2" value=<?php echo "'".$row["telefono_2"]."'"; ?> readonly="readonly">
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label> Parroquia </label>
            <select class="form-control" id="parroquia" readonly="readonly">
            <?php 
                while($row2 = pg_fetch_array($consult2)){ 
                    if($row2["id_parroquia"] == $row["fk_parroquia"]){ ?>
                        <option value=<?php echo "'".$row2["id_parroquia"]."'";?> selected><?php echo $row2["nombre"];?> </option> <?php
                    }else{ ?> 
                        <option value=<?php echo "'".$row2["id_parroquia"]."'";?>><?php echo $row2["nombre"];?></option> <?php
                    }
                }?>
            </select>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12" align="center" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:#CCC" id="guardar" value="Modificar">
            <img src="img/import.ico" height="25" width="25"\> Modificar </button>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12" align="center" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:#CCC" id="eliminar" value="Eliminar">
            <img src="img/export.ico" height="25" width="25"\> Eliminar </button>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div id="errorSection">
        </div>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function IngresarDatos(){
         $("#registrarCentro").find(':input').each(function() {
                 var elemento= $(this).val();
                 if(elemento == ""){
                    alert("   Todos los Campos son Obligatorios \n \n    Por Favor, Ingrese El campo " + $(this).attr("id"));
                    return false;
                }else{
                    var expRegCedula = new RegExp("^\\d{6,8}$");
                    var expRegNombreApellido = new RegExp("^([a-z]|[A-Z]){5,45}$");
                    var expRegCorreo = new RegExp("^([A-Z]|[a-z])([A-Z]|[a-z]|\_|\-|\.|[0-9]){4,20}\@([A-Z]|[a-z]){3,15}\.([A-Z]|[a-z]){2,5}$");
                    var expRegTelefono = new RegExp("^\\d{10,15}$");
                    var expRegUsuario = new RegExp("^([a-z]|[A-Z]|\\d)+$");

                    if(!expRegNombreApellido.test($("#nombre").val().trim())){
                        alert("El nombro solo puede tener letras con un minimo de 5 y un maximo de 45");
                        return false;
                    }else if((!expRegTelefono.test($("#telefono1").val().trim())) || (!expRegTelefono.test($("#telefono2").val().trim())) ){
                        alert("El campo telefonico solo recibe digitos y con un maximo de 15");
                        return  false;
                    }else{

                        return true;
                    }
                }
             });
        return true;
    }


    $("#guardar").click(function(){
        //alert("Entro a modificar");
        if($(this).val() == "Modificar"){
            $("#guardar").prop("value","Guardar");
            $("#registrarCentro *").each(function(){
                $(this).attr('readonly', false);
            });
        }else{
            alert("Entro a guardar");
            $("#guardar").prop("value","Guardar");
            $("#registrarCentro").each(function(){
                $(this).attr("readonly",true);
                if(IngresarDatos()){
                    //alert("entro");
                    $.post("php/IngresarCentro.php", {nombre: $("#nombre").val(), direccion: $("#direccion").val(), telefono1: $("#telefono1").val(), telefono2: $("#telefono2").val(), parroquia: $("#parroquia").val()} , function(data){
                        if (data != 1){
                            $("#errorSection").html(data);
                        }else{
                            alert ("El centro ha sido agregado Exitosamente");
                        }
                        $("#registrarCentro")[0].reset()
                    });
                }   
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Values does change, but you're using button, and you need to change its text also.
Try this code(change value but not text) :

```
$(document).on('click',"#guardar", function(){
    //alert("Entro a modificar");
    if($(this).val() == "Modificar"){
        $(this).val("Guardar"); // change into $(this) and use .val()
        $("#registrarCentro *").each(function(){
            $(this).attr('readonly', false);
        });
    }else{
        alert("Entro a guardar");
       $(this).val("Modificar"); // change into $(this) and use .val()
        $("#registrarCentro").each(function(){
            $(this).attr("readonly",true);
            if(IngresarDatos()){
                //alert("entro");
                $.post("php/IngresarCentro.php", {nombre: $("#nombre").val(), direccion: $("#direccion").val(), telefono1: $("#telefono1").val(), telefono2: $("#telefono2").val(), parroquia: $("#parroquia").val()} , function(data){
                    if (data != 1){
                        $("#errorSection").html(data);
                    }else{
                        alert ("El centro ha sido agregado Exitosamente");
                    }
                    $("#registrarCentro")[0].reset()
                });
            }   
        });
    }
});
```

You want to change button text also, if so use below code?

```
$(document).on('click', "#guardar", function () {

if ($(this).val() == "Modificar") {
    $(this).val("Guardar"); // change into $(this) and use .val()
    $(this).contents().filter(function(i,e){
        if ( this.nodeType == 3 && i == 2 )
            this.nodeValue = "Guardar"; // change button text
    });
    // another rest of the code
} else {
    alert("Entro a guardar");
    $(this).val("Modificar"); // change into $(this) and use .val()
    $(this).contents().filter(function(i,e){
        if ( this.nodeType == 3 && i == 2 )
            this.nodeValue = "Modificar"; // change button text
    });
    // another rest of the code
}
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/5rek1msm/)

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w8f8sv6d/2/)

```
$("#value").on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "Modify") {
        $(this).val("Save");
    } else {
        $(this).val("Modify");
    }



});
```